# Can Gradle compile option affect on multi module automatically?(dexOptions,aaptOptions,lintOptions)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

First of all, I have set full version of Gradle setting on main module(:app), the other modules are: core, constant, feedback...etc

When Gradle build running, will all of the setting mentioned at title will be applied to the other module(from :app, to :core, constant, feedback...)

Androidstudio version: 3.4
Gradle dependencies version: "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2"

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    kapt {
        useBuildCache = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        dexInProcess true
        preDexLibraries true
        maxProcessCount 15
    }

aaptOptions { 
        cruncherEnabled = enableCruncher()
        cruncherProcesses = 0
    }

    compileOptions{
        incremental = true  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth,

You have to apply for individual modules.

options like `lintoptions`, `apptOptions`, `kapt` and `dexOptions` are defined under `android` block which is available only in module level build.gradle

```
android {

      lintOptions {

      }
}
```